# How do i use a custom runtime in a layer? (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers, bun

I am trying to use Bun as a runtime in an aws layer, and i am following the instructions (https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/tree/main/packages/bun-lambda).

But on the AWS dashboard the option "Use custom runtime in function code or layer" is missing:

[image]

Whats the new way of using a layer as a runtime?

I've tried just adding the layer and changing the handler but i am lost,

if you could point me to the correct documentation I'll appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

My issues was with the layer, I was creating the bun layer with windows wsl and that was making it fail. I used the public layer instead.

https://learnaws.io/blog/bun-aws-lambda